# Async Method is not calling in Background mode for WIndows Phone 8.1

Tags: web-services, silverlight, background, windows-phone-8.1, async-await

I created background scheduler for windows phone8.1 silver light web service application. When it calls async method it not pining the server. Without background agent the web service is working fine but in background scheduler it not working .Could any one guide me.The following is my code.

```
  1)  WebservicePortTypeClient client = null;
  2)  client = new WebservicePortTypeClient();
  3)  client.MMAsync(objlog.Stringify(), valueacccoundid.ToString(), valuePushToken.ToString(), "version14");
  4)  client.MMCompleted +=   new EventHandler<MMCompletedEventArgs>(returnmlp);
```

When at step--3 it is throwing following statement in the log.

**The program '[3436] BACKGROUNDTASKHOST.EXE' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[2828] AgHost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)**.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved async web service call using following code.

```
 int intResult = await TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync();
 async Task<int> TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync()
{
 1)  WebservicePortTypeClient client = null;
  2)  client = new WebservicePortTypeClient();
  3)  client.MMAsync(objlog.Stringify(), valueacccoundid.ToString(), valuePushToken.ToString(), "version14");
**await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));**
  4)  client.MMCompleted +=   new EventHandler<MMCompletedEventArgs>(returnmlp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a deferral to indicate when your background task is complete. Otherwise the OS may terminate the background thread before hand. You would do it somewhat like this:

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

    WebservicePortTypeClient client = null;
    client = new WebservicePortTypeClient();
    var result = await client.MMAsync(objlog.Stringify(), valueacccoundid.ToString(), valuePushToken.ToString(), "version14");

    //Do something with result.

    //Add this after your task is complete.
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

More information can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977055.aspx (Refer point 4)

**For Windows Phone 8 styled agents:**

Make the method signature to "protected async override..." and use await keyword for the async method.

```
protected async override void  OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    WebservicePortTypeClient client = null;
    client = new WebservicePortTypeClient();
    var result = await client.MMAsync(objlog.Stringify(), valueacccoundid.ToString(), valuePushToken.ToString(), "version14");

    //Do something with result

    NotifyComplete();
}
```

Comment: Thank you rajshri. I already implemented schedular agent, i am unable to link above process with my solution. How can i call run method.

Comment: @rajaramesh The Run method is an implicit method for all BackgroundTasks in WindowsPhone 8.1. But I guess you didn't use it. Are you using the older Windows Phone 8 style agents? (like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) If yes, I suggest you follow https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977059.aspx to implement the newer Background Tasks module.

Comment: NO i am using windows phone 8.1. I followed following url http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-34-Creating-a-Background-Agent-for-Scheduled-Tasks   for implementing agent.

Comment: The schedular agent,is working fine. But i am unable to link  BackgroundTasks for async method.

Comment: @rajaramesh I saw the link you gave. It is Windows Phone 8 styled background agent (although you can use it in WP8.1 Silverlight as you have done). Have you added a NotifyComplete() in the OnInvoke() method?

Comment: Yes. I added notifycomplete() in oninvoke() method.

Comment: The following is my code.    protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
        {
           
          // Class1 lk = new Class1();

          
            //EMM.Core.MIOsend kl = new EMM.Core.MIOsend();
          //  kl.raja();

           WEbMIO lp = new WEbMIO();
          lp.MIOBACkTransferLOCdata(); // async method implemented in this method

           ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
           NotifyComplete();

        }

Comment: @rajaramesh I edited the answer. I guess using await would fix it.

Comment: If i do like this  var result = await client.MMAsync(objlog.Stringify(), valueacccoundid.ToString(), valuePushToken.ToString(), "version14");  It is saying error that cannot await 'void"